# How to see PCIe device info on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, hardware, pci

I know about `pciconf` but this does not give enough information.  Is there an equivalent to `lspci -vv` in FreeBSD?  I want to know the negotiated link speed, serial number and other vital product data, NUMA nodes, etc.

Regarding Vital Product Data, the man page says `-V` shows it, but none of the devices on my system are showing anything for that.

Here's an example from FreeBSD

```
# pciconf -lbcevV pci0:4:0:0
mpr0@pci0:4:0:0:    class=0x010700 card=0x30e01000 chip=0x00971000 rev=0x02 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'LSI Logic / Symbios Logic'
    device     = 'SAS3008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-3'
    class      = mass storage
    subclass   = SAS
    bar   [10] = type I/O Port, range 32, base 0xa000, size 256, enabled
    bar   [14] = type Memory, range 64, base 0xfb300000, size 65536, enabled
    cap 01[50] = powerspec 3  supports D0 D1 D2 D3  current D0
    cap 10[68] = PCI-Express 2 endpoint max data 128(4096) FLR NS
                 link x8(x8) speed 8.0(8.0)
    cap 03[d0] = VPD
    cap 05[a8] = MSI supports 1 message, 64 bit, vector masks 
    cap 11[c0] = MSI-X supports 96 messages, enabled
                 Table in map 0x14[0xe000], PBA in map 0x14[0xf000]
    ecap 0001[100] = AER 2 0 fatal 0 non-fatal 0 corrected
    ecap 0019[1e0] = PCIe Sec 1 lane errors 0
    ecap 0004[1c0] = Power Budgeting 1
    ecap 0016[190] = DPA 1
    ecap 000e[148] = ARI 1
```

And here is an example from CentOS:

```
# lspci -vv -s :d8:00.0
d8:00.0 Fibre Channel: ATTO Technology, Inc. Celerity FC 16Gb/s Gen 5 Fibre Channel HBA (rev 30)
    Subsystem: ATTO Technology, Inc. Celerity FC-162E
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at ee808000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 4: Memory at ee810000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at ee880000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [54] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [78] MSI-X: Enable- Count=512 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00004000
        PBA: BAR=0 offset=00003400
    Capabilities: [84] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [94] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 2048 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <8us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [f8] Vital Product Data
        Product Name: ATTO Celerity FC-162E Fibre Channel Adapter, FC PF
        Read-only fields:
            [PN] Part number: FC-162E
            [SN] Serial number: SN D-171026-091344
            [FN] Unknown: 46 43 2d 31 36 32 45
            [VB] Vendor specific: PW=12.5W; PCIE X8 GEN 3
            [V1] Vendor specific: ATTO Celerity FC-162E Fibre Channel Adapter
            [V2] Vendor specific: FC
            [V5] Vendor specific: FC-162E
            [V6] Vendor specific: A0:1, D0:1
            [V7] Vendor specific: ID:0316,V:01.01.09.01
            [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 30 byte(s) reserved
        End
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO+ CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC+ UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn+ ChkCap+ ChkEn+
    Capabilities: [12c v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        IOVCap: Migration-, Interrupt Message Number: 000
        IOVCtl: Enable- Migration- Interrupt- MSE- ARIHierarchy+
        IOVSta: Migration-
        Initial VFs: 1, Total VFs: 1, Number of VFs: 0, Function Dependency Link: 00
        VF offset: 2, stride: 1, Device ID: 0064
        Supported Page Size: 000007ff, System Page Size: 00000001
        Region 0: Memory at 000000f000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable)
        VF Migration: offset: 00000000, BIR: 0
    Capabilities: [228 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=ba5d Rev=1 Len=020 <?>
    Capabilities: [1d0 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [1e8 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=c511 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [200 v1] Transaction Processing Hints
        Interrupt vector mode supported
        Steering table in MSI-X table
    Capabilities: [20c v1] #19
```

Comment: `pciconf -lv`, [dmidecode(8)](https://manpage.me/?dmidecode)`dmidecode -s <keyname>` or `dmidecode -t <type>`

Answer (score 5):

Install the `pciutils` package which provide the `lspci` command:

```
pkg install pciutils
```